# How to check the denseness of the operator?

Tags: operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

If $l^2=\{x=(x_1,x_2,x_3,...):\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}|x_i|^2<\infty\}$ and $T:l^2\rightarrow l^2$ is a linear bounded operator defined by

$T(x_1,x_2,x_3,...)=(0,0,x_1,x_2,x_3,...)$ ,where $x=(x_1,x_2,x_3,...)\in l^2 $

then is  $\overline{R(T)}=l^2$ ?

In addition, what is  the best way to prove  closedness and denseness of subspaces related to bounded operators which are defined on sequence space ?

Here $R(T)=\{(0,0,x_1,x_2,x_3,...)\}$

If $x\in l^2,$ then we have to show either $x\in R(T)$ or $x$ is a limit point of $R(T) ~i.e ~for~ every ~\epsilon>0,~S(x,\epsilon)\cap R(T)\neq\phi. $

I don't how to prove or disprove it. please help.

Thanks.

Comment: Hint: can you approximate $e_i$ (vector with $1$ on $i$-th position and $0$ on the rest) with vectors from $R(T)$?

Comment: @mihaild Here $\|e_i-(0,0,x_1,x_2,...)\|=|1-x_{i+2}|.$ So $e_i$ can't be approximated with the vectors from R(T). Am i correct ?

Comment: That equality is not true for most $i$ and $x$. Try to write $e_1 - Tx$ explicitly.

Comment: Range of $T$ is all sequences with first two coordinates $0$ and this set is closed.

Comment: @geetha290krm Could u provide some hints to prove the set is closed ? If possible , kindly suggest some books on operators where I could find similar problems. Thanks.

Comment: The operator $T$ is an isometry i.e.  $\|Tx\|=\|x\|.$ Hence its range is closed, and coincides with $\{e_2,e_2\}^\perp,$ where $e_1$ and $e_2$ are the first two elements of the standard orthonormal basis.